# Как можно сделать такую полосу активного элемента в Bottom Navigation?

Tags: java, android, material-design, navigationbar

Как можно сделать такую полосу на активном фрагменте в navigation bar?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на картинке скорей всего просто TabLayout с иконками, там underSocre из под коробки с анимацией, так делали еще до того как в материал закатили Bottom navigation. Если вам нужен именно Bottom navigation, то там можно получить BottomNavigationItemView и нарисовать полосочку, или что угодно

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei спасибо, а как правильно получить BottomNavigationItemView и нарисовать ?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделал следующим образом. Правда не знаю, насколько это неприлично :)

В разметку добавил пять View элементов с нужной высотой и сделал их прозрачными.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="3dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="3dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="3dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="3dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="3dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Далее в MainActivity при нажатии на каждую из кнопок запускаю функцию, передавая ей соответствующий View. В функции делаю все View прозрачными, а переданный (нажатый) закрашиваю в нужный цвет.

```
private void setBorderActive(View view) {
        v_1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        v_2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        v_3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        v_4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        v_5.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
```